# Getting estimated time to restore rds db snapshot using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-rds

I use python script to restore my RDS DB snapshot to a DB instance. However, I am not able to determine when my instance will be ready to use. Sometimes, it takes 8-10 minutes while other times it takes a bit longer.  Is there a way or a function in boto3 to find out the estimated remaining time for instance creation?

Having this information would be big help.

Thank you!

Comment: There is no way to get an estimate. It takes as long as it takes.

Comment: @MarkB, thanks for the information